# Make plots in a for loop in R with spplot

Tags: r, for-loop, gis

I'm having a little trouble programming stuff in R that I would normally do in a for loop in another language...

I am now trying to make a plot using spplot from the sp package (it's a chloropleth map), but I want to do it for a bunch of variables. In a for loop, I would program it like this:

```
for (TRAIT in c("height","bmi","whr","body_fat","income")){
pdf("plot_of_TRAIT.pdf")
spplot(MyData, "TRAIT", col.regions = my.palette, cuts = 8, lwd = 0.5)
dev.off()
}
```

where each instance of TRAIT should be replaced by the variables I give to the for loop (so in the filename of the pdf, and as an argument in the spplot command). Now, obviously this code does not work, but how would one go about doing this in R?

**UPDATE:**

I got the code to create different pdf files, but the spplot command still will not work. It creates empty pdf files:

```
for (TRAIT in c("height","bmi","whr","body_fat","income")){
outfile <- paste0("plot_of_", TRAIT, ".pdf")
pdf(outfile)
spplot(MyData, TRAIT, col.regions = my.palette, cuts = 8, lwd = 0.5)
dev.off()
}
```

If I run the exact same code outside of the for loop like this:

```
pdf("plot_of_height.pdf")
spplot(MyData, "height", col.regions = my.palette, cuts = 8, lwd = 0.5)
dev.off()
```

it works fine and I get the desired plot in the file plot_of_height.pdf.

**UPDATE 2:**
This seems to be an issue with spplot. If I run this:

```
TRAIT <- "height"
pdf("plot_of_height.pdf")
spplot(MyData, TRAIT, col.regions = my.palette, cuts = 8, lwd = 0.5)
dev.off()
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in [.data.frame(obj@data, zcol) : undefined columns selected
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Have you tried TRAIT instead of "TRAIT"?

Comment: It just creates one "plot_of_TRAIT.pdf" (instead of five, with TRAIT in the filename replaced by the trait names in the for statement), and that plot contains nothing... (also if I use TRAIT instead of "TRAIT"). The piece of code within the for statement does work if I run outside the for loop and manually replace TRAIT.

Comment: Use `paste` to put together the file name, `pdf(paste0("plot_of_", TRAIT, ".pdf")`. Also follow nitish.s's advice. The string in quotes, `"TRAIT"` will always be exactly that, only the object `TRAIT` (unquoted) will take on different values in different iterations.

Comment: I think it would help to see some or all of `MyData`.

Comment: If it helps, MyData is a SpatialPolygonsDataframe that includes data attributes with the names that I use in my for loop (height, bmi, whr, body_fat, and income).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at your data, I cannot say why you have the undefined column error. Replicating your 'UPDATE 2' code with the meuse dataset does not throw the same error for me:

```r
library(sp)
demo(meuse, ask = FALSE, echo = FALSE)
TRAIT <- "copper"
my.palette <- c("black", "red", "green", "blue")
spplot(meuse, TRAIT, col.regions = my.palette, cuts = 8, lwd = 0.5)
```

[image]

As for the first case of your question: `spplot` (much like `ggplot`) won't output anything to the device from within a loop unless explicitly printed. Basically you are opening a pdf file, creating the plot but not saving it to the pdf file, then

The following code should work for you:

```r
for (TRAIT in c("height","bmi","whr","body_fat","income")){
    outfile <- paste0("plot_of_", TRAIT, ".pdf")
    pdf(outfile)
    print(spplot(MyData, TRAIT, col.regions = my.palette, cuts = 8, lwd = 0.5))
    dev.off()
}
```

I tested it using the Meuse dataset and it worked fine there:

```r
library(sp)
demo(meuse, ask = FALSE, echo = FALSE)
my.palette <- c("black", "red", "green", "blue")
for(TRAIT in c("cadmium", "copper", "lead", "zinc")){
  outfile <- paste0("plot_of_", TRAIT, ".pdf")
  pdf(outfile)
  print(spplot(meuse, TRAIT, col.regions = my.palette, cuts = 8, lwd = 0.5))
  dev.off()
}
```

Giving me 4 distinct pdfs, each containing the spatial plot of the corresponding variable.

Comment: If you are interested as to why you have to explicitly print the `spplot` output, this is [R FAQ 7.22](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f).

Comment: It works when I use print, thank you so much! :) Please take my bounty

Answer (score 2):

You need to construct the output file name using the variable.

For example:

```
outfile <- paste0("plot_of_", TRAIT, ".pdf")
pdf(outfile)
```

For `spplot` you probably need to use `TRAIT` (no quotes).

**EDIT:**

Since `spplot(zcol = ...` can be a column number, I wonder if this might work?

```
traits <- c("height","bmi","whr","body_fat","income")
for(i in 1:length(traits)) {
  pdf(paste0("plot_of_", traits[i], ".pdf")
  spplot(MyData, i, col.regions = my.palette, cuts = 8, lwd = 0.5)
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your solution, and I also removed the quotes. It now creates the different pdf files, but they still contain nothing unfortunately. If I run the exact same code outside of the for loop, but with "height" instead of TRAIT in the spplot command, it does work and I get the desired plot.

Comment: How about if you run `TRAIT <- "height"`, then `spplot(MyData, TRAIT, ...)` outside the loop?

Comment: Good point, then it still does not work, but with an error message this time! "Error in `[.data.frame`(obj@data, zcol) : undefined columns selected"

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Unfortunately this still does not work... (same problem, lots of pdf files that contain nothing...)